# Page Break in NDHTMLtoPDF

Tags: ios, html-to-pdf

I got a problem using NDHTMLtoPDF. When I use a html page with a page-break using a div with css class property

```
{
    page-break-after: always
}
```

the created pdf has a margin in the following page. The margin seems to be the same size as the omitted space at the last page. The html seems correct while Safari presented it ok.

Can someone give me a hint how I can remove the margin.

I added a simplified example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Musterseite</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <style type="text/css">
                        *, :after, :before {
                            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                            box-sizing: border-box
                        }
                    @page {
                        size: 21cm 29.7cm;
                        margin-top: 1cm;
                        margin-left: 1.4cm;
                        margin-right: 2cm;
                        margin-bottom: 1cm
                    }
                    body {
                        font-family: Arial;
                        font-size: 11px;
                        line-height: 110%
                    }
                    .pagebreak {
                        page-break-after: always
                    }
                    .block {
                        margin: 15px 0;
                        padding: 3px;
                        border: 1px solid rgba(100,100,100,.2);
                        display: table;
                        width: 100%
                    }
                    .block.first {
                        background: rgba(0,0,0,.05)
                    }
                    .block .heading {
                        display: table-cell;
                        padding-left: 2px
                    }
                    .block h3 {
                        margin: 0;
                        line-height: 180%;
                        margin-bottom: 5px;
                        font-weight: 700;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                        display: inline-block;
                        font-size: 11px
                    }
                    .block .row {
                        display: table-row;
                        width: 100%;
                        font-size: 0
                    }
                    .block .row .group {
                        display: table-cell;
                        vertical-align: top
                    }
                    .block.col-2 .row .group {
                        width: 100%
                    }
                    .block.col-4 .row .group {
                        width: 50%
                    }
                    .block .row .group span {
                        padding: 2px;
                        font-size: 11px
                    }
                    .block .row .group .field {
                        display: inline-block;
                        font-weight: 700;
                        width: 50%;
                        height: 100%;
                        vertical-align: top
                    }
                    .block .row .group .value {
                        display: inline-block;
                        width: 50%
                    }
                    h1 {
                        border-bottom: 1px solid red;
                        line-height: 150%;
                        margin-bottom: 0;
                        font-size: 22px
                    }
                    div.clearfix {
                        clear: both
                    }
                    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

            <div id="wrap">
                <h1>Report</h1>

                <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="group"> <span class="field">Name</span> <span class="value">Mark Test</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="group"> <span class="field">Remarks</span> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="group"><span class="value" style="width: 100%;"></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pagebreak"></div>
                <div id="cat2">
                    <h2>Transport 2</h2>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Cube 1</h3>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Type</th>
                                <td>Small</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Model</th>
                                <td>NDB2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div></body>
</html>
```